# Assign ID's to dynamically generated elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In my application I read an RSS feed. Using zrssfeed (http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/) the elements of the feed are displayed. My problem is that inside each list item, there are three

elements without ID or class.

I want to style each of these

elements differently. How can I achieve this?

```
<div>
 <ul> 
 <li>
         <img />
         <p>text1</p>
         <p>text2</p>
         <p>text3</p>
 </li>
 <li> .. next item... </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve assigning a different ID to each of these elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// after elements have been created
$('li').find('p').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'p_' + i);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/rL2Ea/1/)

You could also use css3's `nth-child` selectors:

```
p:nth-child(1) {
    color: pink;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
    color: green;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
    color: yellow;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/wavCj/1/)